# Just try commiting a Big Project with SVN?

Tags: svn

Committing a Big Project with SVN is a pain . It takes almost 3-4 Hours for to commit a Project of around 60-70 MB ( Symfony + Zend Project ) . I have a Speed of 512 KBPS which is Broadband. SVN Repository is on Codesion

Same Project committed to same Codesion GIT Repository takes maximum 10 Minutes.
OS is Ubuntu Linux

Linus Torvalds created GIT and here he bashes SVN/CVS 
http://buytaert.net/linus-torvalds-on-git

(See Video at the Point -> 3:00 Minutes QUOTE - "Subversion is the most pointless Project ever started :)" Not me but He is saying .

I have always noted GIT to be Zillion times faster due to some GZIP Compression it uses I think . Is there any other reason.

Exact number of Hours is not Important , but Performance I mean.

Why is that ?

Comment: Please add more information about your setup. Where is the repo running? On what kind of server, using what kind of OS?

Comment: @Rohit a difference this big is strange. Have you talked to Codesion about this?

Comment: @Pekka - yes I have written a mail , but since SVN transfers on per file basis , maybe it is normal . GIT and Hg use compression so they are a way faster . Remember from FTP ? Transferring a bunch of Folders always takes Countless Hours ? But just ZIP a folder and transfer over FTP (then unzip on server) - it takes Minutes ? correct no ? maybe same case here

Comment: @Rohit Subversion uses compression as well when transmitting to a remote repo.

Comment: @Pekka Thanks for telling that . I will wait for the Answer from codesion . If SVN uses compresion then some other unknown issue I think , god knows only , but GIT is good anyways

Comment: @Pekka BTW SVN Checkout is blazing fast , so something wrong with SVN Server not witi SVN protocol itself :) How do I delete this Question

Comment: I wonder that if you are committing 60 megabytes of changes then you might be versioning something that you don't need to.  And Yes, Linus has his opinions but his credibility doesn't extend to the entire universe of (software) discourse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no such thing as "no local GIT repos". GIT always has a local repo and you checkin to it, and then you have to explicitly push the local repo to the remote repo. If the remote repo is not populated, that push will have to transfer all 60MB at least once. Even with compression, that data won't be that much less so it takes 3-4 mins. At best at 512Kbps you will transfer 3MB per minute, and that is with optimal saturation of your bandwidth, so 60MB should take at least 20mins.

SVN does have overhead, as it is transferring on a per-file basis. GIT is optimized for batch inter-repos transfers. This will make a difference. On the other hand, you could set a local copy of the SVN repo, checkin locally and then replicate to the remote repo, which will get the performance closer to GIT's numbers. Of course, I doubt any online SVN provider supports thus scenario.

Answer (score 2):

At 512 Kbps, uploading 60 MB of data takes approximately 120 mins(60000/512=117.18). I believe something must be going wrong somewhere while you commit to GIT.

Comment: Maybe he commits into his local GIT repos? There is no network involved. ;-)

Comment: In Git, commits *always* go to the local repository. That's the *whole point* of distributed version control. In DVCS, *committing* and *publishing* are two different things, in CVCS, they are clumped together.

Comment: When talking about internet bandwidth, 512 Kbps is referring to bits, not Bytes. So 512 Kbps is really (512 / 8) = 64 KB (Kilo Bytes) per second. Also, 60 MB it's not 60000 KB, it's (60 * 1024) = 61440 KB. So, 61440 KB / 64 KB = 960 seconds = 16 minutes. And that is if your **upload** speed is indeed 512 Kbps, which is generally not if your ISP package was "512 Kbps", which generally refers to **download** speed.

Answer (score 0):

Network connection speed might be an issue here, as well as performance of machine serving svn or git. I was commiting up to 10GB of files to SVN in less than 3 hours on local machine. Never tried that with GIT though.